# Removing Middle Characters From File Name in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, rename, mv

I'm new to text handling in bash and have hundreds of files with varying names:

```
TS_01_001_21.0.tif
TS_10_005_-21.0.tif
TS_21_010_-45.0.tif
```

I want to remove the middle section and the extension so the files look like:

```
TS_01_21.0
TS_10_-21.0
TS_21_-45.0
```

So far I have:

```
for f in *.tif;do 
   mv "${f}" "${f%.tif}"
done
```

To remove the extension, but I can't figure out how to remove the middle three characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what should happen if you have filenames like `TS_01_001_21.0.tif` and `TS_01_002_21.0.tif` ?

Comment: For such complex name transformations, you are perhaps fastest, if you use the bash regex operator, which can not only match a tring for having a certain structure, but also extract parts of the string. It is described in the bash man-page in the section _Compound Commands_, under the command `[[ expression ]]`. In addition, I would consider using the option `-i` for `mv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `middle` always means `3 digits` plus an underscore (`_`)
- there is only the one (aka `middle`) occurrence of `3 digits` plus an underscore (`_`)
- the extension is always `.tif`

One idea using a pair of parameter substitutions to remove the unwanted characters:

```
for f in TS_01_001_21.0.tif TS_10_005_-21.0.tif TS_21_010_-45.0.tif
do
    newf="${f//[0-9][0-9][0-9]_/}"
    newf="${newf/.tif/}"
    if [[ -f "${newf}" ]] 
    then
        # addressing comment/question re: what happens if two source files are modified to generate the same new file name
        echo "WARNING: ${newf} already exists. [ source: ${f} ]"
    else
        echo mv "${f}" "${newf}"
    fi
done
```

This generates:

```
mv TS_01_001_21.0.tif TS_01_21.0
mv TS_10_005_-21.0.tif TS_10_-21.0
mv TS_21_010_-45.0.tif TS_21_-45.0
```

Once satisfied with the result OP can remove the `echo` in order to perform the actual file renames.